# Simple Command Line Program throws Exception

Tags: java

I know it's an easy question but it creates some unusual problem.

```
public static void main(String [] st) {

    System.out.println("\n\n Arg: :"+st.length);
    for(int i=0;i<st.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("ARGUMENTS: "+st[i]);
    }
}
```

This program prints only "Arg: :0" as Output

I have also tried

```
String s= st[0];
System.out.println("\n String: "+s);
```

but it throws Exception.
so please Help me out of this.

Comment: What's the problem -- there just aren't any arguments. Are you passing any on the command line?

Comment: This program i had run before but just now it will create problem and st [] doesn't have to initialize.

Comment: Can you paste the exception, NullPointException..?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 and when i run this programme it immediately terminated it not even wait for Entering String From Command Line.

Comment: I think people downvote questions very quickly. Let's be a little more patient with the people who need help.

Comment: Are you giving the program any arguments? Can you show exactly how you invoke (start) it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not passing any parameters to the program when you start it then `st` will be empty. Thus trying to reference the first item in the array will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Recently also try this as Suggested by Michael Brewer-Davis         for (String s: st) 
 {
            System.out.println(s);

  
 }But it doesn't display Enythig.

Answer (score 1):

See tutorials on [command line args](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) and [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

One particular difference with C and some other languages is that the program name itself is not one of the arguments, so while a C `main` function always has at least one argument, a Java `main` does not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is complaining that you have an index out of bound exception which means you are trying to access the String at index `0` when there is no such string.

Two ways you can work this out is to look at the exception carefully (assuming you know what it means) or stepping through the code in a debugger which would make this clearer.

Comment: Now , it's working  it's JDK's problem configuration in Eclipse. Thanks for All Answers.